# Gmail not accepting logins in email program

Tags: python, python-2.7

This program works quite well except for when dealing with logging in with Gmail. I wasn't quite sure if this was a problem with Gmail specifically, or a problem with my program. Comcast, AOL, and Yahoo! work fine.

```
import socket
import smtplib

email_provider = raw_input('Gmail, AOL, Yahoo! or Comcast? ').title()
email_user = raw_input('Type in your full email username. ')

email_pwd = raw_input('Type in your email password. ')

if email_provider == 'Gmail' or 'Google': 
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
if email_provider == 'Aol' or 'AOL': 
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.aol.com",587)
if email_provider == 'Yahoo' or 'Yahoo!': 
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.yahoo.com",587)
if email_provider == 'Comcast' or 'Xfinity': 
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.comcast.net",587)

smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(email_user, email_pwd)

sendto = raw_input('Email address to send message to: ')
to = sendto
CC = sendto

subj = raw_input('Subject: ')

header = 'To: ' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + email_user + '\n' + 'Subject:' + subj +'\n'
print '\nMessage Details:' 
print (header)
assignment=raw_input('Enter your message: ')
msg = header + assignment + '\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(email_user, to, msg)
print ('Your message has been sent!')
smtpserver.close()
```

Comment: glad you got your answer. I was thinking that it might be something else, ( very small chance ) but glad that you got your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
if email_provider == 'Gmail' or 'Google':
```

Python works on [truthy values](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).  Anything that isn't `False`, `None`, `0` or an empty collection/mapping will be `True`.

From what it looks like, the execution chain will fall all the way through until it sets your SMTP connection credentials to Comcast's server.

So, effectively, your first statement is saying this:

```
if email_provider == 'Gmail' or True
```

You would want to change it to this:

```
if email_provider in ('Gmail', 'Google')
```

Then, realistically, those could be rewritten as `elif` - only one of those statements are going to be true at any given time.